# Do I need to specify the user:group in sudoers to impersonate other users

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, user-management

I was trying to limit the command a specific user can execute in the sudoers file, say I have something like this:

```
dummy myserver=(ALL:ALL) /usr/sbin/reboot,/usr/sbin/shutdown
```

My dummy user is only allowed to reboot or shut down the system. I intentionally allow the dummy user to impersonate other users, but anytime I try using the -u option of the sudo e.g `sudo -u anotheruser whoami`

I get the following error:

```
Sorry, user dummy is not allowed to execute '/usr/bin/whoami' as anotheruser on myserver.
```

I understand I can specifically call out the user and group I want to impersonate in the sudoers, but I am curious as to why the ALL:ALL doesn't work

I would greatly appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(ALL:ALL)` does work, your `dummy` user is just not allowed to execute `whoami`. You should add `/usr/bin/whoami` to the list of allowed commands. You current rule says that `dummy` can execute `/usr/sbin/reboot` or `/usr/sbin/poweroff` as **any** user and **any** group. You are allowed to call `sudo -u anotheruser /usr/sbin/reboot`, it's failure to reboot the system will have nothing to do with **sudo**.

Moreover there is probably no `/usr/sbin/reboot` and `/usr/sbin/poweroff` executables on your system. These are essential commands, so they should be in `/sbin`.

Summarizing: your `/etc/sudoers` file should contain a line like this:

```
dummy myserver=(ALL:ALL) /sbin/reboot, /sbin/poweroff, /usr/bin/whoami
```

Comment: You made my day, you are the boss man!

Comment: I should also add that if the user you are impersonating doesn't have access to the commands, it won't work.